# Let $f : X \to Y$ be a function and $E \subseteq X$ and $F \subseteq X$. Show that in general

Tags: analysis, functions

Let $f:X\to Y$ be a function and $E\subseteq X$ and $F\subseteq X$.

Show that in general $f(E − F)\nsubseteq f(E) − f(F)$.

I have no idea about how to prove this; and could anyone please explain the basic theory of functions(by relating to this question. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following example: $E=\{a,b\}$, $F=\{b,c\}$, where $a,b,c$ are distinct. Let $f(a)=f(b)=f(c)=0$. (The $b$ is not really needed.)

Then $f(E\setminus F)=\{0\}$. But $f(E)\setminus f(F)$ is the empty set.  So in this case, we have $f(E\setminus F)\not\subseteq f(E)\setminus f(F)$.

**Remark:** The issue is that $f(K)$ on the part $K$ of $F$ that "sticks out" from $E$ can give trouble. Suppose that $x$ is in $E\setminus F$. Then $f(x)$ "wants" to be in $f(E)\setminus f(F)$. But if $f(k)=f(x)$ for some $k\in K$, then $f(x)$ is not in $f(E)\setminus f(F)$. It got removed in the $\setminus$ process.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but if you could help me prove this, that would be great.

Comment: The counterexample is a full proof that we **need not** have $f(E\setminus F)\subseteq f(E)-f(F)$.

Answer (score 0):

consider $X = \mathbb{R} $, $Y = \mathbb{R}^+$, $E = [0,1]$, $F= [-1,0]$ and put $f(x) = x^2$

$$ E \setminus F = E \implies f ( E \setminus F) = f(E) = [0,1]$$

$$ f(E) = f(F) \implies f(E) \setminus f(F) = \varnothing$$

Comment: Ohh okay thank you. but how to prove this questions?

Comment: I did prove it.